# Is it possible to access an object via memory address?

Tags: python, cpython

In CPython, the builtin-function `id(x)` returns the memory address of `x`.
Is it possible to reverse this ?

Something like `object_by_memoryadress(id(x)) == x`.

**Update**: The reason I need this is, because I'm using a program with embedded Python. And in this program I can create so called "Nodes" that can communicate with each other, but only with integers, strings, and stuff, but I'd need to "transfer" a list between them (which is not possible the usual way).

Comment: Yeah, `pickle` can turn almost any Python object into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a shared library that contains the following code:

```
#include "Python.h"
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) PyObject* PyObjectFromAdress(long addr) {
    return (PyObject*) addr;
}
```

compiled it and wrapped it using ctypes:

```
import ctypes
dll = ctyes.cdll.thedll
object_from_id = dll.PyObjectFromAdress
object_from_id.restype = ctypes.py_object()
```

Now you can exchange python objects through their memory adress within one python process.

```
l1 = []
l2 = object_from_id( id(l1) )
print l1 == l2
l1.append(9)
print l2
```

But be aware of already garbage collected objects ! The following code will crash the Python interpreter.

```
l2 = object_from_id( id([]) )
l2.append(8)
```

Comment: I still fail to understand when this would be appropriate. _Why_ can't you exchange a _reference to a list_ between two "nodes"? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: *XPRESSO* is a node based graphical "scripting language". Py4D, the new Python extension for Cinema 4D does also integrate Python into this system. In XPresso, data (like Ints, Strings) is transferred from an Output to an Input. But it does not support exchanging any types of course, only such as integers, etc. Can you now imagine the need ?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Why was none of that included in your original question? It was clearly relevant to any possible solution.

Comment: You are right. With time comes knowledge, you know ? ;) I will include the real facts in my future posts. I often try to cut it down to a shorter but similiar example etc.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to send info between different Python processes running concurrently, check out [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) or celery.

If you're just looking to be able to save / restore / pass around arbitrary Python objects, check out [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) and [marshal](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html).

### Don't do this, it's wrong and bad!

```
>>> x = 'asdd3r3'
>>> b = id(x)
>>> for key, value in globals().iteritems():
...     if id(value) == b:
...         break
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
>>> for key, value in globals().iteritems():
...     if id(value) == b:
...         break
...
>>> print value
asdd3r3
>>>
```

You'd have to repeat this for `locals()` as well. As you can see above, it doesn't work if you're creating a new name in the scope while iterating over the scope's namespace. It is probably also broken in a dozen other ways.

### Don't do this, it's wrong and bad!

Comment: Lol. The problem is, the object I want to get using the desired function is not in the global-scope wether in the local one or in the nonlocal scope. It's in some way in another skript, but in the same process but they cannot communicate with each other in the common way. (I'll add this to the question.)

Comment: If they can communicate the memory address of the item, then they can communicate a reference to the item, or the item itself with `pickle` or similar.

Comment: As the memory adress is an integer, I can transfer it between them. Never used pickling, even don't know what it is. I'll take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `pickle` and `marshal` are how you serialize Python objects. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have never come across a function that could do that no. But you could keep an internal index of every object you create and store it as well as it's memory address. Then do a lookup in the table.